# Can email studio subscriber Lists / Filtered Data Extensions be viewed within SC?

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

Using CM4SF, lists from Campaign Monitor can be viewed in Sales Cloud. Is there a way for someone to view subscriber lists or fitered Data Extensions from Marketing Cloud within Sales Cloud ?

Comment: Nope. You could build something custom, but it’s probably not worth it - what is your use case exactly?

Comment: The use case is a sales cloud user being able to send emails using lists and filtered (sendable) DEs from within Sales Cloud

Comment: But the data originates from Sales Cloud, so what is the point of going back and forth between the clouds? The user could create either a campaign or a report in sales cloud and send directly to that campaign from within sales cloud: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_co_send_single_email.htm&type=5